# Proof of membership in an aggregated BLS signature

Tags: accumulators, bls-signature

Is it possible to prove that a given signature is a part of an aggregated BLS signature? Specifically, given:

- $m_1...m_n$ are $n$ distinct messages
- $p_1...p_n$ are private keys with $P_1...P_n$ being the corresponding public keys
- $S_1...S_n$ are BLS signatures such that $S_i = sig(m_i, p_i)$
- $A = S_1 + S_2 + ... + S_n$ is the aggravated BLS signature

Is it possible to prove that a signature $S_i$ is contained within $A$ using only publicly available data: $A$, $S_i$,  $P_i$, and $m_i$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. What you are referring to is called *local aggregation*. The proof is a small **hint** that is calculated from the set. The verifier can verify a signature on a message without knowing the full set. Thus, the runtime of the verifier is independent of the size of the set; unlike the other answer.

This paper, [Locally Verifiable Signatures and Key Aggregation](https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/179.pdf), from Goyal & Vaikuntanathan was published recently in [CRYPTO22](https://crypto.iacr.org/2022/).

Comment: The first link is broken. I found the preprint https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/179.pdf

Comment: oops thanks for telling me